# Can I use getter and setter in java MVC model

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I have one JFrame and it has one JTextArea.Now I want set text for this JTextArea to show some infomation.I use MVC with pure entity model.Can I use this function in this JFrame class

```
 public JTextArea getTxaTicket() {
    return txaTicket;
}

public void setTxaTicket(JTextArea txaTicket) {
    this.txaTicket = txaTicket;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really think you should set and get only the content of the JTextArea. Not the JTextArea it self.

```
public String getTxaTicket() {
    return txaTicket.getText();
}

public void setTxaTicket(String txaTicket) {
    this.txaTicket.setText(txaTicket);
}
```